# Running python program doesn't work and only gives function address

Tags: python

When I run my python program from terminal with `python sumSquares.py`, I get the following result: `<function diffSum at 0x1006dfe60>`
My program looks like this:

```
def diffSum():
    sumSquares = 0
    for i in range(0, 100):
        sumSquares += i**2

    squareSum = 0
    for i in range(0, 100):
        squareSum += i

    squareSum **= 2
    print (squareSum)
    return sumSquares - squareSum

print(diffSum)
```

Even though I have a print statement at the end, it doesn't actually print the result that is returned; it just prints the function address. Any ideas why this is?

Comment: you need to call this function like this `print(diffSum())`. Currently you are printing `function` object, while what you want to print is object returned from this particular function.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the function by adding parentheses after its name, as in:

```
print(diffsum())
```